# Program keeps repeating itself. (Python)

Tags: python, loops, while-loop, passwords

```
attemptsRemaining = 5


if attemptsRemaining == 0:
    print("Entry failed. Locking program.")
    exit()

while attemptsRemaining > 0:
    passwordEntry = input("Enter the password to access the data: ")

    if passwordEntry == 1234:
        print("test")

    else:
        attemptsRemaining -1
```

So, I'm using Python to write a simple password script, but the program doesn't stop looping the "enter the password" input even after I get it right, and when I get it wrong five times it still loops. Does anybody know how I can troubleshoot this issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are not actually decrementing `attemptsRemaining`.
You need to do the equivalent of `attemptsRemaining = attemptsRemaining - 1`.

More commonly & more concisely, you can do `attemptsRemaining -= 1`.

The other issue you will find (and less obvious) is that when you are calling `input`, the value is going to be stored as a String.  You are comparing against `1234` the integer, so it will always return `False` and never consider your password correct, even when it is `1234`.

And finally, you need to make sure that you `break` out of your `while` loop when the password is correct.  Otherwise, you'll be stuck in the loop!

Answer (score 4):

There are 3 things wrong with your code.

First, you want to break the while loop after entering the correct password.

Second, you have a typo in your else clause:
it should be `-= 1`
`attemptsRemaining - 1` calculates the correct value, but does not assign it back to a variable.

The following code should work for you

```
attemptsRemaining = 5


if attemptsRemaining == 0:
    print("Entry failed. Locking program.")
    exit()

while attemptsRemaining > 0:
    passwordEntry = input("Enter the password to access the data: ")

    if passwordEntry == 1234: # if you get the password correct
        print("test") # print test
        break # and come out of the loop

    else:
        attemptsRemaining -=1
```

Thirdly, you are comparing the value of the user input against an integer. `input()` values are going to be stored as a string, so you are comparing different types that will always return `False`.  You need to either convert `passwordEntry` to an `int`, or compare against `'1234'` the string.

Answer (score 0):

```
attemptsRemaining = 5


while attemptsRemaining > 0:
    passwordEntry = input("Enter the password to access the data: ")

    if passwordEntry == 1234:
        print("test")
        break # exit loop

    else:
        attemptsRemaining -=1

if attemptsRemaining == 0:
    print("Entry failed. Locking program.")
    exit()
```

Answer (score 0):

proper way to execute if statement also. and exit after 5 wrong attempts

```
attemptsRemaining = 5

while attemptsRemaining > 0:
    passwordEntry = input("Enter the password to access the data: ")

    if passwordEntry == "1":
        print("test")
        print (attemptsRemaining)
        break
    else:
        attemptsRemaining = attemptsRemaining - 1

    if attemptsRemaining == 0:
        print("Entry failed. Locking program.")
        exit()
```